# What ux method can I use to verify the success of Subscription Model of my app?

Tags: ux-designer, methodology, subscription

I'm currently have an application project but I cannot disclose more information about it. I would like to know what specific methods can I use to verify if the "Subscription Model" idea that I have is going to work properly. Meaning, I can assure that the users will not unsubscribe and keep on paying on the application. The application does have already a wide network of possible customers so I the first launch will be critical.

Thanks!

Comment: Without clearer information, this question can't be answered.  There is not general answer that applies to all applications, so as it stands it's too broad, and I have to put it on hold.  If you edit the question and add enough information for it to be answerable, it may be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to find users that are likely to use your product/service and **interview** them to see their attitudes towards your idea.

You can also **survey** your target users to gain additional information on their opinions.

You can also try something like an **[A/B test](https://vwo.com/ab-testing/)**. Try 2 or 3 variants of your subscription plan/idea, distribute them evenly among subscribers and see which one of these works best for you and stick with it.

My suggestion is to use both interviews and surveys before the launch and during the launch do an A/B test. Of course you should put great effort to the three methods and do them with minimal bias. You have to improve constantly to at least have a chance to succeed.

Comment: this is a very good answer, but the problem is the OP is asking for some kind of "pre-launch testing" to test just an idea, basically a *crystal ball*

Comment: Try to find target users and interview them. Interview 5-10 people and you will get general idea if they will like the subscription plan. I think interviews for this case would be most beneficial.